# Array manipulation in OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I am manipulating 2-dimensional arrays in OCaml. I have some questions:

1. How to declare an array whose length is of type `int64`, instead of `int`? For instance, `Array.make : int -> 'a -> 'a array`, what if I need a bigger array whose index is of type `int64`?
2. May I write something like the following:

   let array = Array.make_matrix 10 10 0 in
   array.(1).(2) <- 5; array.(3).(4) <- 20; (* where I modify a part of values in array)
   f array ...
   ...
   The code above seems to me unnatural, because we modify the value of `array` inside the `let`, do I have to this, or is there a more natural way to do this?

Could anyone help? thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 64-bit systems, the size of OCaml arrays from the Array module is limited to 2^54 - 1 and on 32-bit systems the limit is 4,194,303.  For arrays of float, the limit is 2 times smaller.  In both cases the index is easily represented as an int, so there's no advantage in using int64 as an index.

The value for 32-bit systems is *way* too small for some problems, so there is another module named Bigarray that can represent larger arrays.  It supports much larger arrays, but the indices are still int.  If you really need to have large indices, you are possibly on a 64-bit system where this isn't such a limitation.  If not, you're going to run out of address space anyway, I would think.  Maybe what you really want is a hash table?

I'm not sure what you're saying about "let".  The purpose of let is to give something a name.  It's not unreasonable to give the array a name before you start storing values into it.  If you want to define the values at the time you create the array you can use Array.init and write an arbitrary function for setting the array values.

Array code in OCaml is inherently imperative, so you will usually end up with code that has that look to it.  I often use `begin` and `end` and just embrace the Algolic quality of it.